# Can you give name of free firewall and free antivirus that does not keep logs (for tor node)?

Tags: firewall

Can you give name of free firewall and free antivirus, preferably with open source code that does not keep logs and information  that can deanonymize the user (for example, any entries (notes, logs) about the ip-addresses of connections to the node, data packets, or any keys, etc.), or another, that can deanonymize users of my entry or relay node of tor if somebody will get physical access to my computer? This question for ensuring safety users who will transmit traffic through my entry or relay node.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because... look at my comment: this answer will fit much better at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I need answers from tor's community users, not all others. Hope you will understand.

Comment: I mean, you can just use Tails OS (https://tails.boum.org), keeps no literally no logs and runs the whole system through the Tor network.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, then the firewall that comes with your distribution. As for antivirus, you don't usually need one for Linux because it's not usually required but you can install [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/) if you really want to.

What you really need to know is **how to disable logging in each program or for the system as a whole**. Since you provided no information on what kind of system that you will be using, just take that as a general guideline of what you need to research.

Comment: Clam AV is an open source antivirus? I want to use kali linux as an entry or relay node system (is kali open source?) I would like to know how to disable logging in kali, I would also be glad if you write how to disable logging in whonix, trisquel and parabola GNU/Linux. Thanks.

Comment: If you click on the link that I sent, it says at the top, "ClamAV® is an open source antivirus engine for detecting trojans, viruses, malware & other malicious threats."

Comment: "sudo systemctl stop syslog"
"sudo systemctl disable syslog"
If the distro uses something different, you should start researching how each one uses logs. Create a new stackexchange question in the Linux/Unix section if you have specific questions about a specific Linux distro but many people will not be happy if you don't do the research yourself first.

Comment: Thanks, you are always very useful, I watched an article about this antivirus, but just in case I decided to clarify, the last question in this thread, is it real to diasble logging in each program, or if it's not neccessary, which applications can see the connections to my node (where
need to disable logging except the system)? Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, R.I.P. ClamAV - it's still a [Cisco project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clam_AntiVirus) - so unless it will change the way as the signatures are distributed to detect a [Bundestrojaner] (https://www.sonntagmorgen.com/staatstrojaner-erkennen/) to English: federal trojan for example - it's *just* better than nothing, but not a remedy by itself